# Live streaming on raspberry pi

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, webserver, webcam, motion

I am trying to livestream to a web server using a USB webcam on my raspberry pi.

My method at present involves using python to take a photo on the webcam every second and is stored in the /var/www/html/ directory of the pi. I have used an apache web server, and written some html/javascript code to the index.html file that picks up the stored image every second and displays it to the user.

Another method I have seen is to stream the webcam data to the pi's ip address using the 'motion' programme, so that when the ip address is visited it shows the webcam stream.

It seems like these are two independent methods. My question are:
In the second method, how is this method working? Is the pi saying, instead of displaying the webcam data to the screen, store it in the ip address instead?

Is apache simply a method to store file that are to be accessed over a network, hence it will not be possible to pass the live stream through the apache web server, as the stream is not a file?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure this is the right place for your question could be a superuser type question. Have you any code that you want people to look at?

Comment: Hi Richard, no code as such, however the 'motion' programme/package I am referring to is here: https://motion-project.github.io

Comment: On further reading, it looks like it streams an mpeg file? Would it be possible to save this to the apache web server /var/www/html area as a workaround to stream the webcam data through the apache structure?

Comment: I really wouldn't know - I'm just a low level moderator and just trying to improve your question. Your question though seems be more superuser or serverfault though if there isn't any code.